# Scroll horizontal overflow div center with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a horizontal ul as tabbar inside a div. When i click on a li element, i want to scroll the parent div center to the viewport. How can i do that without jquery?

```js
const tab1 = document.getElementbyId('tab1');
const tabbar = document.getElementbyId('tabbar');

if (tab1) {
  tabbar.scrollLeft = -tabbar.offsetWidth
} else {
  tabbar.scrollLeft = tabbar.offsetWidth
}
```

```html
<div id="tabbar" class="container">
  <ul class="tabbar">
    <li id="tab1"><a>Tab 1<a/></li>
     <li id="tab2"><a>Tab 2<a/></li>
     <li id="tab3"><a>Tab 3<a/></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What exactly do I need to change about this function so that the container scrolls horizontally into the middle at each resolution when you click on the second li element?

Comment: Can you show a JSFIDDLE for this? I'm not able to understand your query properly.

Comment: Moreover, do you need the page to be scrolled so that the parent DIV is at center or do you want to just place the DIV at the center without scrolling the page?

Comment: @TusharShukla i need the page to be scrolled so that the parent DIV is at center. My Site is avaible at https://ui-ux-design.io - Look at the mobile version and you can unterstand me better, i think

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First get all elements and then add an event listener on each of them.
Then, in the event listener function, find the height of the parent element and height of the screen.
Now, apply the screen top to the window as per the calculations above.

JS:

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks");

tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("uix-tabbar");
    var sTop = (parentDiv.clientHeight/2) + (screen.height/2);
    window.scrollTo(0, sTop);
  });
});
```

Let me know in case any more info is required. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've run this code in console of the link you mentioned and it works as expected (as far as I understood the requirement)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not what I wanted. If you click on the "UI-UX-Design " tab, the container with the ID  "uix-tablotable " should automatically scroll to the left so that the tablabel  "UI-UX-Design " becomes visible and centers in the center of the view. If you then click on the tab  "Webdesign ," the tablabel  "Webdesign" should become visible.

Comment: Do you mean the `active` tab should get centered when clicked?

Comment: Great that you understood me:) That's exactly what I mean... How can i do that?

Comment: Ok,I can't write code as of now (travelling at the moment) but you can achieve this via flexbox; Try changing the `order` property of the active tab item on click of the tab. By using `order: 1|2|3|4..`, you can define the actual order of elements inside a `flexbox`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there you misunderstood me a bit. I don't want to change the arrangement of the tabs. I just want the Tab  "UI-UX-Design " to be centered when you click on it. If you click on  "Corporate Identity " or  "Web design ," these should become fully visible again. Can you follow me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193462/discussion-between-niklas-and-tushar-shukla).